# Why does Tony call his daughter Maguna?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

Tony calls his daughter Maguna a couple of times in the movie. (Or at least uses that word around her. I don't know if that's just a nickname or has a deeper context. Any search on Google yields no proper results regarding "Maguna" in relation to the MCU.)

He also calls her by her full name, Morgan H. Stark. Searching for the name in the comics, I came across [this](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Morgan_Stark_(Earth-616)). Apparently, Morgan is a different person there, an evil cousin of Tony's. I haven't read any comics so I don't know much about the characters there.

There was also a line in *Avengers: Infinity War* where Tony says to Pepper that he wants to name their future child by the name Morgan and that's exactly what they did so where does Maguna come in?

I'm unable to find the Endgame script or images of the scenes where Maguna is mentioned, apologies.

Edit: I know most think it's just a nickname Tony addresses his daughter by and I quite agree but it seems unusual with an interesting story to it, which wasn't mentioned in the movie. I was hoping someone who has good knowledge of the comics side of things might have come across it. If this indeed is the first mention of Maguna in the movie and comic universes, I'm ready to accept the answer mentioning it's a nickname.

Comment: Perhaps it's nothing more than a cute nickname for his dauther.

Comment: Yep, just watched it for the second time. You're definitely right that it's "Maguna"

Comment: Maguna is how a child might speak the name Morgan(a) before it can speak properly, so that might be the simple origin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually he calls her Maguna twice-once outside when trying to find her by the tent, and again when he tells her the “horrible story”...”Once upon a time Maguna went to bed...the end”.

It seems like a pet name given to her, much the same way many fathers have pet names for their daughters. It also could’ve been how Morgan pronounced her name when she was first learning to talk-unfortunately we never got to see that darling child during her toddler years.

Answer (score 15):

This is just a nickname of Morgan for Tony Stark.

There is nothing else significance to this name. Tony was playing with her that's when he calls her Maguna. So, we can assume it's just a cute nickname.

Comment: Yes like Hope's mother calling her Jelly bean and Scott Lang calling his daughter peanut. No significance just a nick name...

Comment: @Jared That could be completely true but it sounded like a highly unusual name (Is Maguna a common nickname in the West? Jellybean and peanut don't seem that uncommon.) and seemed to have some history behind it though it wasn't mentioned anywhere in the movie. I was hoping people who have read the comics might have come across it.

Comment: @A J Have you checked out the comics as well? Is there no mention of Maguna there?

Comment: @Matte In the comics, Tony Stark does not have any children nor is any "Maguna" ever mentioned. Source: I've read a lot of the comics, including the first four books of volume 5 (Marvel NOW!) of Iron Man.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because they want to make the world of the MCU more relatable to our lives and to make Tony feel like an actual father. Scott Lang, for example, calls his daughter "Peanut" all the time, throughout both the *Ant-Man* films and *Infinity War*, so I honestly think it's to make the characters feel more grounded in their universe. Even with its comics, Marvel has always tried to make their superheroes have human-like qualities, like how Peter Parker is always nervous or anxious. It's a nice touch to make you feel like you're a part of their world.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two proposals which are probably very intertwined:

1. [Maguna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maguna) is a **town in India**, North of Ahmedabad (North-West India): In *Spiderman: Homecoming* Tony Stark rescues Spiderman from the bottom of a lake. Later, they talk to each other and Spiderman at some point realizes that Stark isn't in the suit. Instead he's remotely controlling it from some place in India. It happens to be that there is a town called Maguna in North-West India. Morgan might have been conceived there. Although I must admit that I haven't found any time-related connections: Homecoming took place in 2016, Infinity War in 2018.
2. [Maguna is Marathi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/maguna) (an Indo-Germanic language still spoked by 83 million people in India, especially in the state of Maharashtra) and can be translated to "**afterwards**", i. e. his life after Iron Man / Avengers. This makes sense when considering that scene from proposal 1). In this [Quora-post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Tony-Stark-doing-in-India-when-he-is-speaking-to-Spider-Man-Spider-Man-Homecoming-movie) someone assumes Stark to be at a friend's or an associate's wedding. He also includes a picture from *Age of Ultron* where there was an obviously Indian man at the party (right before Ultron introduced himself / itself). Others on that same Quora-post suggested he was there to "center himself". This idea stems from the original script in which Stark tells Spiderman he was in India to center himself. He might have learned some of the language while being there.

Anyway, (fortunately for my arguments), Maguna has been part of the former Maratha Empire and *Mahatma Gandhi* founded his Ashram in Ahmedabad. So, both of my suggestions might be valid or even are valid in conjunction. After Captain Marvel rescued Stark he might have taken Ms. Potts to Maguna, Ahmedabad or some place in Maharashtra to center himself once more, and to conceive

> *Maguna* - *his life **after** Iron Man*

fyi @ all those who say that ***Maguna*** is just a nickname that doesn't mean anything: You are wrong. Try to write a story, and you will understand very fast that there is nothing like "doesn't mean anything" in an author's mind when composing a tale, especially one of this spectacularity.

Answer (score -1):

Easy, the reason lies with the storytellers, the writers, or the creators of the scene, which isn’t always the writers. They wanted to make the audience believe that they may have a dog or other domesticated animal, but most likely a dog. This is plainly obvious, with the words said before the nickname is uttered, “chow time.” Which is usually said for animals, and only really said for humans in a comedic, satirical manner. After all, Maguna sounds like a pet name, while Morgan is a human name, and human names aren’t usually used for pets. Regarding, the second time it’s used, they figured they use the nickname at least once again, so it isn’t so forcefully placed to trick the audience. In any case, it’s a bit far fetched as a nickname for the name Morgan. It is kind of like the forcefully added splash of water when Stark was washing dishes. He was so adamant in his decision about “keeping what he has,” and only a photo could be used to somewhat believably sway his opinion, and so begins the story. It’s all about storytelling.

Comment: Sorry, what? What point are you trying to get across?

Comment: Damn, I must of not explained myself and my point. Oh wait, just reread what I wrote, never mind.

Answer (score -2):

Alright, this was bothering me as well. We will never know for sure until the bros confirm why they chose “Maguna” as a precious nickname for Morgan H Stark, but here is my best guess.

Tony is intelligent, as is Pepper, and we can assume if Tony calls Morgan “Maguna” there is a fair chance Pepper also called her daughter this pet name, as many parents do this. I’d like to think they took these as root words and combined them for a pretty nickname. The name “Mag” means pearl, and the name “Una” means the personification of truth, beauty, and UNITY. I’d like to think that once Tony found out about the confirmed pregnancy of Morgan, since he already knew because he has visions, that he decided this baby would be his “stone”. He is protective of Morgan at all costs. He immediately turns down Steve because he refuses to jeopardize losing Morgan. I also believe ultimately having Morgan brought Tony to a new level of peace from the pain he was enduring for YEARS after Civil War and she became the unity the Avengers needed to bring everyone back. She is even mentioned when Tony offers the peace offering of Cap’s shield.

It’s also possible that Maguna is a nickname relevant to his mother (or of course pepper’s family) but I haven’t looked into that at all. I think about that because the H in Morgan H Stark likely stands for Howard, so it would make sense that his nickname for his daughter would be related to his mother because we know how much he loves his mom.

Answer (score -2):

Maguna means Humor, forgiveness and shrewdness. An apt nickname for Tony's daughter. Simple as that.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?